# LWJGL vector not loading into GLSL fragment shader?

Tags: java, glsl, lwjgl

I'm loading a Vector3f into my fragment shader as a uniform variable, but it loads into the shader as an empty vector. Right before loading it into the shader, the vector is (1, 0, 0). When it gets passed into the fragment shader, it is (0, 0, 0).  All other vectors are getting loaded just fine.

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;
in vec3 surfaceNormal;
in vec3 toLightVector[4];
in vec3 toCameraVector;

out vec4 out_color;

uniform sampler2D backgroundTexture;
uniform sampler2D rTexture;
uniform sampler2D gTexture;
uniform sampler2D bTexture;
uniform sampler2D blendMap;

uniform vec3 lightColor[4];
uniform vec3 attenuation[4];
uniform float shineDamper;
uniform float specularity;

void main(void) {

vec4 blendMapColor = texture(blendMap, pass_textureCoords);

float backgroundAmount = 1 - (blendMapColor.r + blendMapColor.g + blendMapColor.b);
vec2 tiledCoords = pass_textureCoords * 100.0;
vec4 backgroundColor = texture(backgroundTexture, tiledCoords) * backgroundAmount;
vec4 rColor = texture(rTexture, tiledCoords) * blendMapColor.r;
vec4 gColor = texture(gTexture, tiledCoords) * blendMapColor.g;
vec4 bColor = texture(bTexture, tiledCoords) * blendMapColor.b;

vec4 totalColor = backgroundColor + rColor + gColor + bColor;

vec3 unitNormal = normalize(surfaceNormal);
vec3 unitVectorToCamera = normalize(toCameraVector);

vec3 totalDiffuse = vec3(0.0);
vec3 totalSpecular = vec3(0.0);

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if(lightColor[i].x == 0 && lightColor[i].y == 0 && lightColor[i].z == 0) {
        continue;
    }

    float distance = length(toLightVector[i]);
    float attenuationFactor = attenuation[i].x + (attenuation[i].y * distance) + (attenuation[i].z * distance * distance);

    vec3 unitLightVector = normalize(toLightVector[i]);

    float nDotl = dot(unitNormal, unitLightVector);
    float brightness = max(nDotl, 0.0);

    vec3 lightDirection = -unitLightVector;
    vec3 reflectedLight = reflect(lightDirection, unitNormal);

    float specularFactor = dot(reflectedLight, unitVectorToCamera);
    specularFactor = max(specularFactor, 0.0);
    float dampedFactor = pow(specularFactor, shineDamper);

    totalDiffuse = totalDiffuse + (brightness * lightColor[i]) / attenuationFactor;
    totalSpecular = totalSpecular + (dampedFactor * specularity * lightColor[i]) / attenuationFactor;
}

totalDiffuse = max(totalDiffuse, 0.2);

vec4 color = vec4(totalDiffuse, 1.0) * totalColor;
if(color.a < 0.5) discard;

out_color = color + vec4(totalSpecular, 1.0);

out_color = vec4(attenuation[0].x, attenuation[0].y, attenuation[0].z, 1); **USING FOR DEBUGGING**
}
```

Where I'm loading the vector:

```
public void loadLights(List<Light> lights)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        if(i < lights.size())
        {
            super.loadVector(loc_lightColor[i], lights.get(i).getColor());
            super.loadVector(loc_lightPosition[i], lights.get(i).getPosition());
            //super.loadVector(loc_attenuation[i], lights.get(i).getAttenuation());
            super.loadVector(loc_attenuation[i], new Vector3f(1, 0, 0));
        } else {
            super.loadVector(loc_lightColor[i], new Vector3f(0, 0, 0));
            super.loadVector(loc_lightPosition[i], new Vector3f(0, 0, 0));
            super.loadVector(loc_attenuation[i], new Vector3f(1, 0, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

In the fragment shader, I made the output color equal to each part of the vector (r to x, g to y, b to z), and the result is always black (0, 0, 0).

EDIT: The code for the loadVector method is as follows:

```
protected void loadVector(int loc, Vector3f val)
{
    glUniform3f(loc, val.x, val.y, val.z);
}
```

Comment: Are you calling glUseProgram before you load the uniforms? You have to do so or OpenGL won't know which shader program to use.

Comment: @javac Yes, I am. Like I said, each one of those vectors being loaded in the loadLights method are being loaded correctly.